# Find control point on Quadratic Bezier Curve

Tags: flutter, math, graph, graphics, bezier

I drew a Quadratic Bezier curve. Here A(0, 1.39) and B(30, 1.42) are two points and curves drawn with a single control point (15.02, 6.07).
[image: Quadratic Bezier]

I want to move point B along the curve. But When I move the curve shape changes. So I want to move the control point also with respect to point B.

Pic: Point moved but not control point moved so curve disoriented.
[image: Curve Distorted by Moving B Point]

Pic: Point and Control point moved, so the curve is in proper shape.
[image: CP is also moved]

The blue shape is for reference. Kindly help me to find the control point on moving point B.

Comment: if you need a sub path of your bezier path use `PathMetric` class

Comment: Even if it doesn't seem like it, what  you're trying to do is [split the curve](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#splitting) and then only show the first of the resulting set of two curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subdivide curve onto two new smaller curves. To calculate control point of "left" new curve, when you subdivide large curve at parameter t (in range 0..1):

```
left_P[1] = large_P[0] * (1-t) + large_P[1] * t
```

All points of left curve:

```
left_P[0] = large_P[0]   //initial point
left_P[1] = large_P[0] * (1-t) + large_P[1] * t   //control point
left_P[2] = large_P[0] * (1-t)^2 + 2*large_P[1] * t*(1-t) + large_P[2] * t^2   //last point, coincides with your moving point
```

For your example `t` is about 0.7, and

```
new_C = 0.3*A + 0.7*C
```

Comment: Thanks, but on doing this the curve gets inverted.

Comment: It's strange.Added description for all control points